# Intuition understanding of bootstrap

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bootstrap

I want to estimate the population mean using 100 samples.
The reasonable estimate of the population mean is the sample mean.
I am wondering, why bootstrap can give more accurate result than the sample mean? I mean, when I am doing resampling, will I get more information about the sample in order to infer the population parameter?

Comment: This question might be of interest: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26088/explaining-to-laypeople-why-bootstrapping-works/26093#26093

Comment: The bootstrap mean equals the sample mean, so it will *never* give a more accurate result for this particular estimator.  The bootstrap might give you useful information about the sampling distribution of the mean.