# What statistical techniques are most suited for studying complex adaptive systems?

Tags: bayesian, modeling, stochastic-processes, frequentist

What statistical techniques are most suited for studying (socio-technical) complex adaptive systems? (preferably ones suitable for a non statistician social scientist.

This is in concert with agent based modeling etc.

I was going with bayesian inference and nonparametrics due to its flexibility, quantification of uncertainty etc , but am scared off by the following line of discussion: 
[1](https://errorstatistics.com/2015/01/08/on-the-brittleness-of-bayesian-inference-an-update-owhadi-and-scovel-guest-post/), [2](https://errorstatistics.com/2016/01/11/on-the-brittleness-of-bayesian-inference-owhadi-scovel-and-sullivan-published/), [3](https://itschancy.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/when-does-bayesian-inference-shatter/).

Comment: This is too unclear a question to be understandable by most readers of the forum. Could you try to make it more precise or more focussed? Thank you.

Comment: Things mentioned in the link here: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/462/ 
"By studying systems with many strongly-interacting components, students will learn how stochastic models can illuminate phenomena beyond the usual linear/Gaussian/independent realm, as well as gain a deeper understanding of why stochastic models work at all."

Comment: Also things like heavy tailed distributions.

Comment: ps_I am also scared by those discussions!