# Inconsistent outcomes of boostraped hypothesis tests on max and median

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, median, extreme-value

I am trying to make an hypothesis test using bootstrapping.

I compute a quantity `Q` from a sample set (the exact calculation should not be relevant, but let's say that `Q` is the average time between two particular events). I have `N` different sample sets, so that I have `Q1...QN`.

I am interested on the following two quantities:

- `Q_max`: this is the maximum of (`Q1, ... QN`)
- `Q_05`: this is the median of (`Q1, QN`)

`Q_max` and `Q_05` are therefore two different statistics which depend on N different sample sets.

I want to test the hypothesis  that `Q_max` is larger than 0, and also that `Q_05` is larger than 0, i.e., the maximum average and the median average are larger than 0. Note: the same procedure should work for every percentile.

I start with the null hypothesis which assumes that all the `Qi` are 0 (which would imply that the median and the maximum and all other percentiles are also 0), i.e., I subtract the mean `mu1` from the first sample `s1` to obtain sample `p1`, so that `Q1` is zero, etc.

Then I apply bootstrap as follows. I re-sample (with replacement) from `p1`  and compute the average `E1`, I do the same for all samples so that I get all averages `E1..EN`. Then I compute `E_max=max(E1..EN)` and `E_05=median(E1..EN)`. I do the same process 10000 times, now I have an empirical distribution of `E_max` and `E_05`.

Now I can compute the p-value of (the initial) `Q_max` and `Q_05` to reject the null hypothesis. Assume I decide that the max p-value is 0.1.

I have two questions:

- I obtain that the p-value of `Q_max` is 0.15 (so I cannot reject the hypothesis that the maximum of the means is 0) **but** I obtain a p-value of 0.06 for `Q_05`. This implies that **the median is larger than 0 but the maximum is not significantly larger**. How is this possible? By logical arguments the maximum should also be larger than 0 if the median is larger than 0?
- Is the method described above OK?

Comment: You say "the exact calculation should not be relevant...", but you actually must verify that the distribution of this test statistical is *pivotal* under the null hypothesis in order to apply the bootstrap for inference.

Comment: Be *very* wary of trying to bootstrap a maximum. It typically doesn't work. [Even the median can run into difficulties, especially with small samples -- sometimes people modify their bootstrap procedure (such as moving to a smoothed bootstrap) when dealing with the median.]

Comment: @AdamO: yes, we can assume that the distribution is pivotal, I just tried to avoid details which I thought are not relevant

Comment: @Glen_b: what's about testing that the median is >0 on a very large sample and then infer that all quantiles >0.5 (including the max therefore) are also positive?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at - how would that relate to discreteness problems in small samples?

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrapping primarily works in the center of your distribution.  It works progressively less well as you try to bootstrap quantiles towards the tails of your distribution.  It necessarily fails when trying to bootstrap the minimum value or the maximum value.  It may help you to read @Cardinal's excellent answer here: [What are examples where a "naive bootstrap" fails?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9722/7290), which explicitly discusses bootstrapping the max.

Moreover, trying to test the max of a distribution doesn't make much logical sense (as you note).  If you believe the median is >0, there is no need to try to test the max also.  In addition, most distributions that people work with are treated as unbounded, meaning that the true population max is $+\infty$.  It may help you to read some of CV's treads that pertain to the max.  Clicking on the tag ([maximum](/questions/tagged/maximum)) and sorting by `votes` will let you start with the highest rated threads.

Comment: thanks, I am in the meantime aware of the problems in estimating the max. However, I'd like to stress that I am not really interested in the max itself, I am only interested to know if the max is (significantly) larger than 0 using a hypothesis test. If this is still an issue, do you suggest to just test that the median (or let's say the 0.75 quantile) is larger than 0 and then infer that all larger quantiles (including the max) are also positive? Thx

Comment: What kind of data do you have? The max is presumably $+\infty$ (ie >0).

Comment: No, the max is bounded, it is the time between two events which I know is between 0 and 10'000 seconds.

Comment: If your data are bounded [0, 10,000], then the max is >0.

Comment: well, I actually subtract 200 as in reality I want to test that the max is larger than 200...so interval is [-200, 9800], sorry for the confusion

Comment: You still don't need a hypothesis test. If you have *any* data >200, then the max is >200. If you really need a p-value, p = 0.

Comment: each data is a statistic (sample average) which in turn depends on another sample, i.e. I want to know if the maximum average is >0. So if I observe one sampled average >200 can I conclude that the  sample with the maximum **true** (unobserved) mean has a mean which is >0?

Comment: It's hard to say. I gather there is a lot more going on in your data than I'm aware of. Most likely you should be fitting a multilevel model, and the random effects terms would be assumed to go to infinity. If you wanted them bounded, you'd probably have to do some heavy coding to fit the model & get the test. I strongly suspect that a test of the max isn't really coherent, though, & comes from people believing that everything needs a p-value.

Comment: yeah it is a tricky problem.. I have N timeseries, each has an average value, and I want to test if the max (or the median) of these N averages is positive. There is no theoretical underlying model. That's why I thought the bootstrapping is a good method to reject the null hypothesis that all the means are 0 (and hence the max is 0). In other words, I want to make sure that if I would have N random series with 0 mean each I would not obtain a similar max average value than the one which I compute from my data, does this make sense to you?